# What Is The Product Functor

Tags: category-theory

I was reading a paper which refrenced something called a "product functor". The was a functor mapping from $\bf{Sets}^{C^{op}}$ for some category $C$. I was wondering what this was?

Thanks for any help

Comment: can you put a link to the paper?

Comment: Mapping from $Sets^{C^{op}}$ to which category?

Comment: Isn't a *profunctor* are you looking for? A profunctor from $\bf C$ to $\bf D$ can be defined as a functor ${\bf D}\to{\bf Sets}^{{\bf C}^{op}}$...

Answer (score 3):

A *profunctor* is probably what you want, as Berci suggested in the comments. Given two categories $\mathcal{C,D}$, a *profunctor* from $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ is a functor $\mathcal{D}^{\text{op}}\otimes\mathcal{C}\to\mathbf{Set}$. Profunctors are adjunct to functors $\mathcal{C}\to\mathbf{PShv}_{\mathbf{Set}}(\mathcal{D})$, where $\mathbf{PShv}_{\mathbf{Set}}(\mathcal{D})$ is the category of $\mathbf{Set}$-valued presheaves on $\mathcal{D}$. It is also a discrete opfibration over $\mathcal{D}^{\text{op}}\otimes\mathcal{C}$. However, I do not know if you mean "profunctor" or "product functor".

If you do indeed mean the latter, then the following is the definition of a "product functor$^{1}$". Anyway, let $\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}$ be the product category of $\mathcal{C}$ with itself. The product functor is the functor $\prod:\mathcal{C\times C\to C}$ such that

- $\prod(X,Y):=X\times Y$ (the [binary product](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aBinary_Product_%28Category_Theory%29));
- $\prod(f,g):=f\times g$ (the [product morphism](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aProduct_of_Morphisms)).

The product functor is a functor, as [this proof shows](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Product_Functor_is_Functor). It is the right adjoint to the diagonal functor, so $\left(\prod\dashv\Delta\right):\mathcal{C\times C\to C}$.

---

$^{1}$ <sub>I do not know how and/or where $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}}$ comes into this picture.</sub>

Comment: Some people prefer to define profunctors $C \to D$ as functors $C^{op} \times D \to \text{Set}$.

Comment: I would never answer a question which is not clear enough to be answerable ...

Comment: @Qiaochu Yes, that is indicated in the nlab's page on profunctors.

Comment: @Martin Hence, I explained two possibilities for what the OP might mean.